# Facebook Graph API search returns empty data for some Keywords

Tags: facebook-graph-api, search

I'm making facebook graph api call for search user. Query is https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=vijay&type=user&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN. 
I got empty response like {"data": []}.

But I'm make same API call with full name of user https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=vijaykrishnan&type=user&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN. Hear I got correct response.

I tried it via my application and Graph API Explorer. I got same result. Is there any issue in facebook side?

Comment: Did you find any answer? We're finding that this happens randomly and will affect all search, with or without a token. Also, while it effects our dev machines (remote) and local machines (local), it does not effect web server. That's 3 different IPs...

Comment: I filed a FB bug in case anyone else is experiencing similar problems with the search http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/456910301017301?browse=search_509b0c1b72a008e55394686